# Mysql query in java restful webservice

Tags: java, jpa

**I have a restful webservice done in netbeans.  I have the following class entities and query.**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findAll",
                query = "SELECT u FROM Users u"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findById",
                query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.id = :id"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByName",
                query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.name = :name"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByTelephone",
                query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.telephone = :telephone"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByYear",
                query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.year = :year")})

public class Users implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Size(max = 25)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "telephone")
    private Integer telephone;
    @Column(name = "year")
    private Integer year;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }

    public void setTelephone(Integer telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    public Integer getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(Integer year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Users)) {
            return false;
        }
        Users other = (Users) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null)
                || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "glee.Users[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }
```

Well, I want to use such a query from this class. for example :

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Padres.findByPass", query = "SELECT p FROM Padres p WHERE p.pass = :pass"),
```

Here are my doubts:
I created another class to try this query:

```
@Stateless
@Path("ws.gleegoo")
public class aaa extends AbstractFacade<Padres> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "WsBbaPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public aaa() {
        super(Padres.class);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/consulta")

    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String returnTitle() {
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Padres.findByPass")
                .setParameter("pass", 2);
        return "<p>" + query + "<p>";
    }

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }
}
```

### This does not work ...

My idea is not to show the pass. It is simply to learn to consult the bd. Because after I try a method that receives the pass and name from an android application and compare with those of the bd and I return a true or false.

If anyone knows better than to tell me.Thanks

Comment: Please re-read your question. You show us a Users entity (which should be named User, BTW), and then ask how to query for Padres? We don't have any idea what Padres is. And naming a class `aaa`, seriously? Also, you really don't want to display a Query. You want to display the *result* of a query. To do that, you need to execute the query. Read the api documentation. Finally, this has nothing to do with MySQL, web services and netbeans, and everything to do with JPA. Choose the appropriate tags.

Comment: You're right I formulated the question wrong. I'm going to change it, thanks